# Different counters for likes in the site and likes in the Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a site with a Like button and a certain amount of likes in the site and  I have a Facebook page, with other amount of likes.
I understand that if I change the href of my site to that of the Facebook page I will have a unique counter for both, the site and the Facebook page.

Now, is there a way I can unified this counter without loosing the likes I already have on my site?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to migrate fans from an Open Graph page to a Page on facebook.com

Comment: Thanks Igy for your quick answer!